# Debugging run time error while running Salesforce Android application

Tags: hybrid, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am working on salesforce android sdk, I am new to this. I have created a simple hybrid app but while running that app in emulator it's giving error:

> unfortunately test has been stopped.

"test" is my project name which i am running. I am using jdk 1.7.0_55. **How can I debug this ?**

Comment: Can you see any error details in console or LogCat view?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of debugging an android application is via the logcat panel of the android IDE (either the old eclipse ide or the new Jetbrains based one).

If you're unfamiliar with that, you can always execute

```
adb logcat
```

on the command line. This will use the android debug (adb) command line tool to run logcat in the terminal. However, so far as I'm aware, this only works with apps running on hardware.